# Is it possible to access GCP resources using api without a user interaction.?

Tags: rest, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Most of the document I found about GCP, the REST API needs a user interaction for authentication. Is there a possible way to access the GCP resource without an interaction from user.?

eg: I would like to implement a cron job in my local workstation to launch a GCP machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, this is that [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#service_accounts) are for:

> A *service account* is a Google account that represents an
>   application, as opposed to representing an end user.
>
> > **Important**: For almost all cases, whether you are developing locally or in a production application, you should use service
> >     accounts, rather than user accounts or API keys. You can use a service
> >     account by providing its private key to your application, or by using
> >     the built-in service accounts available when running on Google Cloud
> >     Functions, Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google
> >     Kubernetes Engine.
>
> All GCP APIs support service accounts. For most server applications
>   that need to communicate with GCP APIs, we recommend using service
>   accounts, as they are the most widely-supported and flexible way to
>   authenticate.
>
> For more information, see [getting started with authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

You'd have to create a service account representing your application (executed as the cron job) and in your application you'd authenticate the REST API calls using that service account's credentials.